# Invalid Segment Alignment iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, binary

I am getting following error by apple for my uploaded binary.

> Invalid Segment Alignment - The app binary at
>   '/Payload/MyAppName_iPhone.app/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources.bundle/GPPCommonSharedResources'
>   does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with
>   the latest Xcode version.
>
> Invalid Segment Alignment - The app binary at
>   '/Payload/MyAppName_iPhone.app/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle/GPPShareboxSharedResources'
>   does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with
>   the latest Xcode version.
>
> Invalid Segment Alignment - The app binary at
>   '/Payload/MyAppName_iPhone.app/GooglePlus.bundle/GPPSignIn3PResources'
>   does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with
>   the latest Xcode version.

any solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to bring you the bad news, but the [GooglePlus bundle has been totally deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/upgrading-sdk) "and is likely to not function as expected. Do not use Google+ Sign-In in new apps." (according to that page I linked to).

If it weren't for the migration message, I'd simply tell you to recompile the GooglePlus SDK using the latest version of Xcode, but the more correct answer is to follow the [directions in the "Google Sign-in quick migration guide"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide).